# Migrating Widgets in Telerik Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-4

I fell into a project where my task was develop some widgets in Sitefinity 4.4. I've found a lot of documentation on how to create the widgets using the Site Manager and all that has gone really well.

Now, I have the widgets set up in a test environment and working well with some test pages. I'm trying to figure out how to deploy the widgets to the production server without re-doing all the work there.  I just want to move the widgets over - I don't need or want the pages.  I have gone through a lot of the Telerik documentation, but have been unable to find anything about deploying like this.  Has anyone done this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you develop these widgets as compiled controls (dll) or simple user controls (.ascx)?

The process is mostly the same for either. the dll goes in the bin folder whereas a user control gets uploaded to the website folder somewhere. then you simply register the widget in the toolbox.

here is the documentation for how this is done: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/adding-controls-to-the-toolbox

The only difference for a compiled dll widget is to use the fully qualified name for the **ControlType** instead of the path to the user control.

After registering the widget it should be available to drop onto any page.

Hope this is helpful!